# What is the grammatical interpretation of じゃ　ありません?

Tags: grammar, conjugations

I have learned in school that じゃ　ありましん　is the "non-past negative" conjugation of です.

Example:

> 私は日本人じゃありません。
>
> "I am not Japanese."

I have noticed that じゃ　ありません contains the pronunciation of the negative form of あります.

From a strictly grammatical point of view, does じゃ　ありません say that something doesn't exist? If so, what is the grammatical purpose of attaching じゃ to the proceeding word?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, じゃ is a contraction of では, where は is the topic particle. The construct ではありません is then seen to be the negative form of であります with a は inserted, and であります is a formal version of です.

So perhaps the real question is, what is the purpose of で? It carries most of the semantic load: there a few other constructions meaning "to be" of the pattern で + (verb of existence), e.g. である, でございます, でござる. So you could say that で means "to be", with the caveat that it is not itself a verb. Of course, by "to be" here I only mean the sense of the linking verb and *not* the existential verb.

My own preference is to say that で means something like "as". Then 〜である etc. translate as "to exist as ...", or in short, "to be ...".